# Converting a graphviz Source object to graphviz Graph object

Tags: python, graphviz, dot

I've got a template schematic made in raw .dot format, but I now want to populate the labels using python.

with the https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/ library I've managed to load the .dot file but don't see how I can edit it. Is it possible to convert a `Source` object to a `Graph` object, or otherwise use the methods available to the Graph object?

trying:

```py
from graphviz import Source

src = Source('digraph "the holy hand grenade" { rankdir=LR; 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> lob }')
src.node("foo")
_ = src.render('test.gv', view=False)
Source.from_file('test.gv')
```

I get the error `AttributeError: 'Source' object has no attribute 'node'`

Answer (score 3):

Following the great answer of @Ray Ronnaret, this is what worked for me.
I have no comments in my dot file, thus it becomes as simple as follows:

```
from graphviz import Source, Digraph

s = Source.from_file('viz.dot')
g = Digraph()

source_lines = str(s).splitlines()
# Remove 'digraph tree {'
source_lines.pop(0)
# Remove the closing brackets '}'
source_lines.pop(-1)
# Append the nodes to body
g.body += source_lines
```

Then, I was able to edit the graph.

```
g.graph_attr['rankdir'] = 'LR'
g.unflatten(stagger=3).render()
```

Answer (score 1):

I do parse the `grapviz.source` eliminate non necessary char and append back. This work for me. Note that this assume first line may be contain comment. Thing remains is to make it be function.

```
src = Source.from_file('Source.gv')
lst = str(src).splitlines()
HasComment =  (lst[0].find('//') != -1)

IsDirectGraph = False
skipIndex  = 0

if HasComment:
    skipIndex = 1
    if lst[skipIndex].find('graph {')!=-1 :
        IsDirectGraph= False
else:
    if lst[0].find('graph {')!=-1 :
        IsDirectGraph= False 

if IsDirectGraph:
    g = Digraph()
else:
    g = Graph()
    
g.body.clear()
        
s = str()
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if( (i>skipIndex) and (i!=len(lst)-1) ):
        if HasComment:
            g.comment = lst[0].replace('//','')
        g.body.append(lst[i])
print(g.source)       
display(g)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz/issues/76

answers the question that it is not possible with that library, but other ones are available  which can.